# Replicate a local mysql db to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds, database-administration

I have a local MySql db and want to replicate it into a Amazon RDS instance.  The Amazon RDS instance functions as a backup.

I looked through the AWS console and didn't find any place to configure it. Anybody knows how to do it?  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you don't have the ability to do this in RDS.  If you want to do this kind of thing, you'll have to implement your own mysql server on an EC2 instance then, you'll have full control over the server, but also full responsibility to configure the backups as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up ongoing replication from on-premises MySQL to RDS MySQL or MariaDB:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html

> You can set up replication between an Amazon RDS MySQL or MariaDB DB
>   instance and a MySQL or MariaDB instance that is external to Amazon
>   RDS. Use the procedure in this topic to configure replication in all
>   cases except when the external instance is MariaDB version 10.0.2 or
>   greater and the Amazon RDS instance is MariaDB. In that case, use the
>   procedure at Configuring GTID-Based Replication into an Amazon RDS
>   MariaDB DB instance to set up GTID-based replication.

Answer (score 0):

Tungsten may help you to replicate from local to RDS. I still didn't try it but the following guide seems to be clear about it.

https://docs.continuent.com/wiki/display/TEDOC/Replicating+from+MySQL+to+Amazon+RDS

Answer (score 0):

It's supported.

> You can use replication to export data from an Amazon RDS MySQL 5.6 DB
>   instance to a MySQL instance running external to Amazon RDS. The MySQL
>   instance external to Amazon RDS can be running either on-premises in
>   your data center, or on an Amazon EC2 instance. The Amazon RDS MySQL
>   DB instance must be running version 5.6.13 or later. The MySQL
>   instance external to Amazon RDS must be running the same version as
>   the Amazon RDS instance, or a higher version.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html

Disclaimer:

> Replication to an instance of MySQL running external to Amazon RDS is
>   only supported during the time it takes to export a database from an
>   Amazon RDS MySQL DB instance. The replication should be terminated
>   when the data has been exported and applications can start accessing
>   the external instance.

So if it's permanent, it would be a better idea to use [tungsten-replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/).